# Redirect to Custom Success Page on Netlify with Angular 6

Tags: angular, netlify

I have deployed an angular 6 site on Netlify with very little problems and I have gotten a form working for simple submissions using Netlify's built in forms.

I am now trying to redirect to a custom angular component after a successful form submission and am a little stuck. I have tried to simulate the documentation for this task that is listed for react and vue on Netlify's documentation in what I imagine is the angular equivalent.

I have tried redirecting to a static html page as well as a component. POSTing to '/' like the documentation suggests results in a 404.

I am getting no errors in the console and after a form submission so I'm not really sure what I could try next. Any input is helpful and I can show the code I used if needed.

**EDIT**: Here is the form that I am using to redirect to Netlify's built in confirmation page. I would love to be able to redirect to my own confirmation component in Angular.

```
<form name="contact" action="/done/" netlify method="POST" netlify-honeypot="bot-field">
  <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact"/>
  <p class="hidden">
    <label>Don’t fill this out if you're human: <input name="bot-field" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Name <input type="text" name="name" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Email <input type="email" name="email" required/></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Message <textarea name="message"></textarea></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Here is a screenshot of a successful form submission that correctly redirects except instead of my angular component, Netlify is still handling the redirect page.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a normal pug site. Did you ever figure out a solution to getting the redirect working? The URL path is correct, like yours, but it just uses the default Netlify confirmation screen irregardless of the URL.

Comment: @ekfuhrmann I haven't had time to go back and try to fix this yet, but I recently got an email from someone who said they had fixed the problem by "sending the form via fetch". I'm assuming that means the browsers fetch API.

Answer (score 3):

For the redirects to work correctly you will probably need a `_redirects` file.

With this file all URLs will be send to the root of the application, allowing the Angular router to function properly.

The `_redirects` file should be created in the `src` folder of your application. For most basic sites the file only needs to contain this line:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

After creating the `_redirects` file you should also add it to the `assets` section in your `angular.json` file.

```
 "assets": [
     "src/favicon.ico",
     "src/assets",
     "src/_redirects"
 ]
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/).

Comment: I already have the redirects file in place and redirecting from other components is working fine. I was asking about the automatic redirect that happens when a Netlify Form is submitted. I want the Netlify form to submit and then instead of redirecting to the Netlify "successful submission" page I want it to redirect to my custom Angular component.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, could you show the code you are using to create the form?

Comment: No worries! I have appended the form code that I am using to my original question @bas-de-groot

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://harrycresswell.com/articles/forms-with-netlify/):

> ...create a new page, for example `/success/` and add an `action` attribute to your `<form>` tag.

It should look something like this:

```
<form name="contact" method="POST" action="/success/"  netlify>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put action="/your page" without the .html in the form tag, which will direct you to your success page.